# How can I get statistics regarding how close I am to the Tenacious badge?

Tags: support, badges

How can I get statistics regarding how close I am to the Tenacious badge?

For those who don't know or don't remember, the Tenacious badge is awarded for

> Zero score accepted answers: more than 5 and 20% of total.

Comment: Which statistics? How close you are? How many people have them?

Comment: I want to know when I can get Tenacious badge, and want to know amount of my post that help me to get Tenacious badge.

Comment: Okay, I'm about to edit your question for clarity, Feel free to @ msg me if you think I edit too far

Comment: Now, regarding the actual question, there's a number of queries in the Stack Exchange Data Explorer dealing with Tenacious/Unsung Hero. I've got to sleep now, but I can come back later and post the best query I find later if someone else hasn't already.

Comment: If you were truly tenacious, you would not care :-)

Answer (score 11):

This query will likely help you. https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/78402/how-many-more-accepted-answers-do-i-need-until-tenacious-unsung-hero

Just enter your userid in the input box

```
http://stackoverflow.com/users/1407421/mehdi-lotfi
                               ^^^^^^^ - thats your userid yay!!!
```

I tested it with my id and it seems to give the correct figures.

Comment: But what is the *To Tenacious* and *To Unsung* table rows there? Is is the percentage of required answers to get that badge?